# AsyncStorage not working on release but working on debug (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native, asyncstorage, react-android

```
 "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.15.5",
 "react": "17.0.1",
 "react-native": "0.64.2",
```

Here's how I use my Async

```
fetch('',{
... //codes here
.then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

     AsyncStorage.setItem('user_token', JSON.stringify(responseJson.token));
     AsyncStorage.setItem('user_id', JSON.stringify(responseJson.data));
     AsyncStorage.setItem('login_type', 'LocalLogin');
     
   });
});
```

then after that here's how I get my asyncstorage

```
const [getData, setGetData] = useState();

const initializeData = async() => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user_id');
    if(userToken)
    {
      setGetData(JSON.parse(userToken));
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    initializeData();
  },[]);

useEffect(() => {
    getUserData();
,[navigation,isFocused]);

const getUserData = async() => {
 var formBody = JSON.stringify({email:`${getData.email}`});
 fetch('',{ ... //more codes here
}
```

I should get the updated data from my API but it seems like the `getData` is null and also it should work because I am re rendering the components. Fetch is working fine because I can login . the main problem i am having is the `AsyncStorage` . Did someone encounter this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw it on my adb logcat that it can't store too much data

So what I did is I chopped my data and store only the needed data . That's what I did.

Comment: its bc https://react-native-async-storage.github.io/async-storage/docs/limits

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition where initializeData and getUserData will both be called on mount, and getData won't be set yet.

You can fix the race like this.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (getData) getUserData();
,[navigation,isFocused,getData]);
```

Comment: still don't work . i tried debugging on logcat adb and confirmed that it don't work

Comment: you will still need this fix

Answer (score 0):

**AsyncStorage** size is set to **6MB** by default, but when it comes with a lot of data you have to increase the size.

If you want to store all data you can update the property seen below.

File: ***android/gradle.properties***

```
AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB=10
```

or

```
AsyncStorage_db_size_in_MB=15
```

depends on how much data you would like to store.

Comment: but it is not recommended to use the asyncstorage for storing too much data .

Comment: so when you have a lot of data to store, what can you do as solution?,i think you can increase the size of storage

Comment: what you need to do is either use a database or chopped the data that's it